# Как в строке найти и вывести все слова, начинающиеся на букву N и слова оканчивающиеся на букву P?

Tags: python

Как в строке найти и вывести все слова, начинающиеся на букву N и слова оканчивающиеся на букву P?

Буквы N и P вводяться пользователем. Попробовал вот так, но не работает:

```
r = input("Введите текст на английском:").split(" ")
n = input("Введите N:")
p = input("Введите P:")

l = []
z = []

for i in r:
    if r.startswith(n):
    l.append(i)

for i in r:
    if r.endswith(p)
    z.append(i)

print(f"Слова которые начинаются на заданую букву :{l}")
print(f"Слова которые начинаются на заданую букву :{z}")
```

Comment: Добрый день! Желательно бы привести код, который у Вас получился. Что уже пробовали, что не работает?

Comment: по логике вещей обрезаете первую и последнюю буквы, а далее по буквенно читайте, если буква N, то все внутри добавляете в ответ, до буквы P, далее снова поиск до буквы N, итд

Comment: @СлаваНосков вы усложняете ;) есть же startswith() и endswith() для строк

Comment: Имхо можно взять слово и по индексу сравнить первую и последнюю буквы и все. В общем ждем попытки и дополним если что не так.

Comment: вы потеряли двоеточия и отступы, немного перепутали названия переменных, но в целом - код рабочий... добавил в ответ исправленный вариант

Comment: @Jack_oS Спасибо вам большое, я и забыл про отступы после if)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [запросите буквы](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input): на которую должны начитаться и на которую заканчиваться
- запросите у пользователя строку со словами;
- [разделите ее](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) на слова по пробелу
- для каждого из них проверьте, [не начинается ли](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) оно и [не
  заканчивается ли](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) заданными буквами
- если да - выводите на печать

Т.е. ваш немного измененный код:

```
r = input("Введите текст на английском:").split(" ")
n = input("Введите N:")
p = input("Введите P:")

l = []
z = []

for i in r:
    if i.startswith(n):
        l.append(i)

for i in r:
    if i.endswith(p):
        z.append(i)

print(f"Слова, которые начинаются на заданую букву: {l}")
print(f"Слова, которые заканчиваются на заданую букву: {z}")
```

при

```
>>> Введите текст на английском:>? 
qwer tyui oper asdf ghjf klui gzxcv
>>> Введите N:>? 
g
>>> Введите P:>? 
r
```

выведет:

```
Слова, которые начинаются на заданую букву: ['ghjf', 'gzxcv']
Слова, которые заканчиваются на заданую букву: ['qwer', 'oper']
```

PS проверить слова можно в одном цикле:

```
for i in r:
    if i.startswith(n):
        l.append(i)
    if i.endswith(p):
        z.append(i)
```